# Angular : Same route switch component view

Tags: angular

I have an angular module that is supposed to push a new view component after a successful form submission, is there anyway to push a new view and use the same route?

Current Routes setup

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
   component: HomeComponent,
    resolve:{
      pageContent: AppResolveService,
     },
     
 },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent,
  resolve:{
    pageContent: AppResolveService,
   },
},
{ path: 'support', component: SupportComponent,
  resolve:{
    pageContent: AppResolveService,
   },
},
{ path: 'download', component: DownloadComponent,
  resolve:{
    pageContent: AppResolveService,
   },
},
];
export const appRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Current Download Module:

```
<div class="download-page">
  <div class="section--main download-page__content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <download-regestration></download-regestration>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could I just bind a value in the Module?

Comment: Could always just use ngIf and use a flag to decide which elements to show

Comment: I thought of that the view is nested and I need to switch the view when the form component is submitted

Comment: I tried eventEmitter bubbling which has worked to switch my state!